# Odoo pos ReceiptScreenWidget _super() functionality not working properly

Tags: javascript, odoo-11, pos

I have included some functionionality for ReceiptScreenWidget(using _super()) in my custom module, so that i can include some more logic in that function. But it is executing only after page load.

How to make it work along with the actual function.

Here is the code:

```js
odoo.define('extended.screens', function (require) {
var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
screens.ReceiptScreenWidget.include({
    show: function() {
        this._super();
        console.log("inside show custom>>>");
}
});
})

Now the "inside show custom>>>" message is printing in console only after page load.
```

Comment: What do you mean?, it should work ok like just that

Comment: Am new to backbone js, i want the inherited function to work immediately after parent function same like python

Comment: And it should work like you have defined. `ReceiptScreenWidget` is not a backbone js model, it's an Odoo screen widget so you could use `include` and call super like you have done, or better using the generic `this._super.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: @AxelMendoza Thanks for the info. I have used the same